# Look up table, enum or a function to return value from key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have two models, Tutor and Student. Tutor can have multiple Topics he can cover, and Student can have multiple Topics he would like to learn. There are 10 possible topics (in string).

I am thinking of creating a Topic table, which contain topic strings. But it would create unnecessary repetition of these strings (making table heavy). So I create a Topic table which contains only topic key.

However, I am undecided about how to retrieve value:

First, I can create another lookup table, which maps a key to string value. This will result in an extra merging step.

Second, I can have a class function that belongs to Topic, that returns string from value.

Which way would be more efficient in my situation? Is there a better approach that I haven't thought of?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there really any reason to differentiate a Tutor from a User other than an additional flag or role assignment?

Comment: Yes, there are (registering etc.). But I think in this context, it is a minor detail. I can implement Topic with polymorphic relationships to Tutor and Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. IMO "topics" sounds like something that need managing, and may change.

If that's the case, there should be a topic table, with an id, name, probably a description, etc. Both tutors and students would `have_many` topics `:through` a join table. Topics would `belong_to` both.

There are several implementations options, including a polymorphic association of topics.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Could you help me to understand why topic table approach would be better than having a class function to map key-value? IMO, changing function should be equally easy?

Comment: @AdamNYC Easy for a developer, sure. And if that's the only person you want to be able to add/edit/delete/etc. topics, fine. Seems like an artificial restriction to me, considering how light the alternative is.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. You are right. I need to think beyond one-man shop here :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Tutor model could be rolled into a User model with role assignments, setup a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between Users and Topics.  This sets up a join table where the foreign keys are listed to join the heavier rows together.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for additional description.

The alternative is to use just a `has_many` association but it lacks a join table so the Topic entries will need to be duplicated for each instance.

Comment: That's why there's has_many:through. Some say that replaces habtm, although if there's *never* going to be additional data alongside the association, habtm seems reasonable to me. I've been taken to task for that, though, so there's some debate.

Comment: Thank you both, Nick and Dave. I think I'll use has_many :through b/c I might need to add new topics.